# How to check which process is running in the background in android OS ?

Tags: android, performance, background, android-service, android-broadcast

I am using `galaxy 5` with android version api 21.

It shows that my application is running in background(at Active Application page).
[image]

Although there is no broadcast receiver or service that run when the application in the background.

How could I know why my application run in background ? any suggestion !

I note that my apps keeps log this log all the time:

```
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=Pelephone wifiLabel="bbbb"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="bbbb"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020113/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0202c9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_h mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02011f/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_h mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02012b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020466/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080907/android:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:20.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:20.474 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:20.594 953-1126/? I/WifiStateMachine: CMD_RSSI_POLL : calculateWifiScore in!
10-23 11:33:20.604 953-1126/? I/WifiStateMachine: CMD_RSSI_POLL : calculateWifiScore out!
10-23 11:33:20.604 953-1126/? I/WifiStateMachine: CMD_RSSI_POLL : out!
10-23 11:33:20.644 30796-3115/? D/com.onavo.network.traffic.SystemTrafficMonitor: Running..
10-23 11:33:21.154 953-1759/? D/ConnectivityService: returning getActiveNetworkInfo :[type: WIFI[] - WIFI, state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "bbbb", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]
10-23 11:33:21.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=Pelephone wifiLabel="bbbb"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="bbbb"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020113/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0202c9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_h mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02011f/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_h mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02012b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020468/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080907/android:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
10-23 11:33:21.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:21.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:21.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:21.464 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:21.474 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:21.474 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:21.474 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
10-23 11:33:21.474 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: applyOpen
10-23 11:33:22.864 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 11 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x3 gsm|lte level=3
10-23 11:33:22.864 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 11 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x3 gsm|lte
10-23 11:33:22.864 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=3
10-23 11:33:22.874 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Phone three bars.
10-23 11:33:22.874 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=Pelephone wifiLabel="bbbb"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="bbbb"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020113/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0202c9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_h mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02011f/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_h mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02012b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020468/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_no_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080907/android:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
10-23 11:33:23.234 953-1564/? D/BatteryService: level:13, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3761, temperature: 326, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303749, invalid charger:0
10-23 11:33:23.234 953-1564/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:450, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000
10-23 11:33:23.234 953-953/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
10-23 11:33:23.244 953-953/? D/MotionRecognitionService:   mReceiver.onReceive : ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
10-23 11:33:23.244 953-953/? I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged
10-23 11:33:23.244 953-953/? I/MotionRecognitionService: setPowerConnected  = true
10-23 11:33:23.244 1170-1170/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-23 11:33:23.254 1170-1170/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
10-23 11:33:23.264 1170-1170/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true
10-23 11:33:23.274 1170-1170/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:13 status:2 health:2
10-23 11:33:23.274 1170-1170/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:13 status:2 health:2
10-23 11:33:23.274 1170-1170/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:13 status:2 health:2
```

and this one :

```
10-23 11:08:11.254 18149-20878/? I/TaskManager:TaskManagerActivity: Observer(Mem)-Madeed:45.70MB
10-23 11:08:11.254 18149-20878/? I/TaskManager:TaskManagerActivity: Observer(Cpu)-Madeed:%0.31
10-23 11:08:11.504 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 8 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x3 gsm|lte level=3
10-23 11:08:11.504 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 8 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x3 gsm|lte
10-23 11:08:11.504 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=3
10-23 11:08:11.504 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Phone three bars.
10-23 11:08:11.514 953-1069/? D/BatteryService: level:12, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 3727, temperature: 329, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303749, invalid charger:0
10-23 11:08:11.514 953-1069/? D/BatteryService: online:4, current avg:450, charge type:1, power sharing:false, high voltage charger:false, capacity:280000
10-23 11:08:11.514 953-953/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
10-23 11:08:11.514 953-953/? D/MotionRecognitionService:   mReceiver.onReceive : ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
10-23 11:08:11.514 953-953/? I/MotionRecognitionService: Plugged
10-23 11:08:11.514 953-953/? I/MotionRecognitionService: setPowerConnected  = true
10-23 11:08:11.514 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: Nothing, mRoamingIconId = 0
10-23 11:08:11.514 1170-1170/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: refreshViews connected={ } level=3 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mobileLabel=Pelephone wifiLabel= emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel=No Internet connection mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020113/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_3 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020415/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_3_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0202c9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_h mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02011f/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_h mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x0/(null) mQSWifiIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020466/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_inout mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080907/android:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
10-23 11:08:11.514 1170-1170/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-23 11:08:11.514 1170-1170/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
10-23 11:08:11.524 1170-1170/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true
10-23 11:08:11.524 1170-1170/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:12 status:2 health:2
10-23 11:08:11.524 1170-1170/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:12 status:2 health:2
10-23 11:08:11.524 1170-1170/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:12 status:2 health:2
10-23 11:08:12.704 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: getRunningAppPackageList()
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Hidden Pkg] - pkg:com.sec.android.app.taskmanager
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Hidden Pkg] - pkg:com.android.incallui
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.maxmpz.audioplayer
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.settings
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.android.daemonapp
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.onavo.android.onavoid
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.whatsapp
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.cleanmaster.security
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.android.app.videoplayer
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.antivirus
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:org.hola
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.google.android.gms
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.dsi.ant.server
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.bluetooth
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.instagram.android
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.samsung.android.fingerprint.service
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.ayce
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.exchange
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.samsung.android.app.headlines
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.samsung.sec.android.application.csc
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.google.android.talk
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.spp.push
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.systemui
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.android.app.parser
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.android.pagebuddynotisvc
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.samsung.android.MtpApplication
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.server.telecom
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.samsung.android.app.galaxyfinder
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.stk
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:android
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.providers.media
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.samsung.android.providers.context
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.shazam.android
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.android.phone
10-23 11:08:12.734 18149-20877/? I/TaskManager:PackageInfo: RunningApp[Service] - pkg:com.sec.android.service.sm
10-23 11:08:13.314 18149-18149/? I/TaskManager:TaskManagerActivity: updateTotalMemory()1387352064, 1.29GB
10-23 11:08:13.864 30796-14502/? D/com.onavo.network.traffic.SystemTrafficMonitor: Running..
```

Comment: Background process in terms of application specific or android os specidfic.?? I think OS...

Comment: I was referring to application specific. as the system shows my app is active just because it do a background task . right ? but I don't know why my application running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get list of running tasks:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("Running task", "Running task: " + tasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString() + "\t\t ID: " + tasks.get(i).id);
}
```